# Swift: Implementing custom merge policy

Tags: swift, database, core-data, merge

I'm building an OSX app using Swift, with Coredata as my data layer. As part of this, I have table that lists a large number of files, with metadata associated with each. Each record can include a URI that points to one of three services it can be hosted on.

```
1. title   created_at   size   uuid   source_local   source_remote   source_cloud
```

I generate all the records using information pulled from the local source. These records all have a `source_local` string.

Later I import a number of records from the remote source. These records are all added and have a `source_remote` string.

A number of these records are hosted on both services, and have matching UUIDs. There is a unique constraint on the UUID field, and I want Swift to merge these two records' fields in some way when it has a constraint error.

I've tried:

`NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy`
and
`NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`

But these policies result in one record completely trumping the other.

Currently I have to work around this limitation by checking if a record already exists with the UUID and updating the existing record with any missing fields in the new file.

However this feels non-optimal – is there a way to create a custom merge policy, in order to have Swift automatically handle conflicts in this way? At this stage I am not concerned with whether the Store or Memory record trumps the other, as long as I can correctly the merge the `source_*` fields.

Thanks

Comment: You can subclass `NSMergePolicy` and write your own code for it. I've never done it, so I won't write an answer about it, but that's where you would start.

Comment: The excellent book _Core Data_ by Florian Kugler and Daniel Eggert has an example how to implement a custom merge policy. The relevant code can be found [here](https://github.com/objcio/core-data/blob/master/Moody/MoodyModel/MoodyMergePolicy.swift).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to @tom-harrington for his nod to extend NSMergePolicy. Huge oversight on my part that I hadn't even considered going down that route.

While exploring how NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy/NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy are implemented, however, I realised that this issue stems from a misunderstanding on my part. These policies already handle conflicts at a property level. Rather than discarding the entirety of one of the object states on conflict, they compare each property and only apply the policy to those properties which have both changed/exist.

NSOverwriteMergePolicy and NSRollbackMergePolicy are policies that will result in one of either object A or B being completely discarded on conflict.